# Re load UIImage after game restarts

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have a game that uses the photo library. You pick a photo from the library and then you go on to the next screen and the photo is there. You play the game, and then when its finished you have an option to restart the game again. I have everything working up to this point. The problem I am facing now is when the game restarts, the photo does not re load. I have searched all over for a solution, but there is nothing I can find to help me out.

So basically I need a way for the game to save the photo so the user can continue playing with that photo after they press re start. Does anyone have any ideas how I can achieve this?

Note: The photo can be overwritten if the user decides to choose a different photo, as long as the new photo gets saved.

Thank you for your time

***EDIT***

This is in my MenuViewController

```
    -(void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    self.myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"game" sender:self];
    [self saveImage];

}

-(void) saveImage {

    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
    NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name
    [pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]; //Write the file
}
```

Then in my ViewController (where the image loads for the game

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
[copter setImage:image];


}
```

And on my restart button

```
 - (IBAction)refreshTheGame {


        UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;
        ViewController *svc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GML"];
        svc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES];
        [self loadSavedImage];
    }

    -(void) loadSavedImage {

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
        NSData *pngData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:pngData];
        [copter setImage:image];
    }
```

Comment: Some code please!! We can't guess why your code is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user chooses the photo you could save the data from the `UIImage` out to file with a known file name, and just load it up next time the game restarts.  To save a `UIImage` to file:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameImage.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

And to load it up again:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"gameImage.png"];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];            
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Alternatively, you could store the UIImage outside of your game data, so that you can load it again next time without having to hit the file system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have tried what you said, but it still wont re load on re start. I have posted the code above, am I missing anything else? Thanks mate

Comment: @user2632573 I assume that `-refreshTheGame` is in the same class as the `-viewDidLoad` method above? If so, try inserting `[copter setImage:img];` as the last line in the `-refreshTheGame` method. It looks like you're reloading the image from the file correctly, but then you're not doing anything with it.

Comment: Hi and thanks, but unfortunately even by adding that line is still not reloading that photo. I have tried many different ways but the photo never comes back. I'm not sure if this makes any difference, but the image in the ViewController is just an empty UIImageView, then when I select the photo from the MenuViewController and press play, it loads that photo into the UIImageView. When I restart the game, the UIImageView is empty again, and no image appears at all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out what I was doing wrong. I have edited my code above with the working code.